# How can I create a custom swipable tab bar like this in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, layout, widget

[image]

I want to create a tab bar like the one above which can be swipable with animations. I tried doing this with the default Tab bar widget in **Flutter** but failed miserably. How can I make this tab bar swipable with animations?

What is the logic behind bringing the selected tab animation down from "Friends" tab to "Family" tab?

I figured out the `onHorizontalDrag` property from the `GestureDetector` widget to do the swiping but still can't wrap my head around switching the tabs with animation.

It'd be so great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet and did you try `PageView`?

Comment: No I didn't try the PageView. Even if it's pageview, will there be animations?

Comment: yes, you can find physics there, also you can use `itemBuilder` from `PageView.builder` for more customization.

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet for this? It'd be of great help to me, brother.

Comment: i think i will prefer `IndexedStack` in this, just give me some times.

Comment: Waiting for your answer!

Comment: Im missing animation on my custom layout .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is made using `PageView` and customAppBar. However, if you want clickEvent on tabBaritem, wrap with `GestureDetector` make a `callBack` or `stateManagement` to hold index.

**Result**

[image]

**MainWidget**

```
class BU extends StatefulWidget {
  BU({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BUState createState() => _BUState();
}

class _BUState extends State<BU> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widgets = [
      ...List.generate(
        5,
        (index) => Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: index.isEven ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Text(
            "Item $index",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ];

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        setState(() {
          /// you can ceil foor
          _selectedIndex = controller.page!.toInt();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  late List<Widget> widgets;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          AppBar(
            selectedItem: _selectedIndex,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: PageView(
                  controller: controller,
                  children: [...widgets],
                )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**TabBar**

```
class AppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedItem;

  const AppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectedItem,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              TabItemChip(
                isSelected: selectedItem == 0,
                text: "Profile",
              ),
              TabItemChip(
                isSelected: selectedItem == 1,
                text: "About",
              ),
              TabItemChip(
                isSelected: selectedItem == 2,
                text: "Friends",
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              TabItemChip(
                isSelected: selectedItem == 3,
                text: "Family",
              ),
              TabItemChip(
                isSelected: selectedItem == 4,
                text: "Settings",
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**TabBarItemChip**

```
class TabItemChip extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final String text;
  const TabItemChip({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      height: 40,
      width: 140,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isSelected ? Colors.cyanAccent.shade700 : Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, pal. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Then feel free to close the question by accepting this as an answer.